# Substrings after the & sign are missing

Tags: php, mysql

```
$mystring = "DTI ORIENTATION: CONSUMER PROTECTION & LEMON LAW";
```

After doing this,

```
$mystring = htmlspecialchars("DTI ORIENTATION: CONSUMER PROTECTION & LEMON LAW");
```

I'm now getting an echo of just "**DTI ORIENTATION: CONSUMER PROTECTION**". 
Even if I removed the **htmlspecialchars** after, the string is different now.

The words after the **&** sign are missing along with it. What just happened? I just want to make the **&** sign to be included in my string to be used in mysqli_query. Please enlighten me on this one. Thank you.

code from file1.php:

```
$(".t_title").click(function(){
            var title = $(this).data("title");
            var training_date = $(this).data("tdate");

            location.href = "viewTrainingAttendees.php?title=" + title + "&tdate="+ training_date; 
        });
```

code from viewTrainingAttendees.php:

```
<?php 
                        $ttitle = $_GET['title'];
                        echo $ttitle;

                     ?>
```

Comment: Can you show more code? because I just tried this and it works well.
What version of PHP do you have? also, `htmlspecialchars` will transform `&` into `&amp;`.

Comment: I see you edited the question.
As @RaymondNijland said, check your field type in MySQL, 90% sure it's a `varchar` type with a limit of 20 chars (or something less than your string's length) probably.

Comment: Php Version 5.2.17. I already updated the question.

Comment: I think I understand now. Your question is not clear and doesn't point out the real problem IMO. What I can grasp by seeing your code is that you want to pass the title in GET method, right?

Comment: Your code does not contain a call to `htmlspecialchars` after all, so where is this coming from? What happens if you really **only** call it on the given string and output that?

Comment: Yes sir. At first (before using htmlspecialchars), the string passes completely. But after using it, that thing happened.

Comment: It's entirely unclear how `htmlspecialchars`, MySQL, that Javascript snippet and URLs are related here. The fact is that `&` has a special meaning in both HTML and URL query strings, and you need to properly encode values respectively for HTML and URLs as needed.

Comment: I removed the htmlspecialchars() and let the $_GET['title'] pass to the variable $ttitle. But still, the words after the & don't appear anymore.

Comment: I understand now. It's not on the php side but on how to pass the string on the URL. Thank you guys for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` has special meaning in a query string, it marks the start of the next key=value pair.

If you want to represent it as data, you have to percent encode it.

Use `encodeURIComponent()` on any plain text string you are inserting into a URL.

Better yet, use the URL API to construct query strings instead of mashing strings together. (You'll need a polyfill for old browsers).

```js
var url = new URL(location.href);
url.pathname = "viewTrainingAttendees.php";
url.searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
url.searchParams.append("title", "DTI ORIENTATION: CONSUMER PROTECTION & LEMON LAW");
url.searchParams.append("tdate", "example example");
console.log(url.href);
```

Comment: I tried this one : 

$(".t_title").click(function(){
    var title = $(this).data("title");
    var training_date = $(this).data("tdate");
    
    location.href = "viewTrainingAttendees.php?title=" + encodeURIComponent(title) + "&tdate="+ training_date; 
   });

It works! But am I doing this right?

Comment: Thank you @Quentin

Comment: You should be encoding *all* the plain text strings, including `training_date`.

Comment: I tried using your code, but how to go to viewTrainingAttendees.php?

Comment: Yay! Okay I got it now. Thanks a lot Sir. Thank you so much.